# Colorize Graylog search results

Tags: graylog2, graylog

Is there any way to colorize or, in general, apply styles to results table on Graylog 2? I'm talking about the *search* result table.

Basically, our logs have a *level* field and we want to add colors on the result table based on its value, so they can be easily recognized. E.g: Error messages should be red, warning messages yellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible with Graylog (as of version 2.1.1) but might be in the future using [message decorators](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/queries.html#decorators).